# React Router Dom catch all routes not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to protect a route by checking

a. user is authenticated. If the user is not authenticated then redirect them to the login page

b. user has a cart. If no cart, then redirect them back to cart page to add items.

For an example , if a user wants to access the checkout page. The user must be first loggedIn and then the user must have items added to his cart.

Now the guards , I would like to separate it two different components

a. to check if user is logged - NewAuthenticatedRoute.jsx

b. to check if user has a cart - CheckoutRoute.jsx

```
//NewAuthenticatedRoute.jsx
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import useAuthenticated from "../../hooks/useAuthenticated";
const NewAuthenticatedRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuthenticated();
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) => {
        return isAuthenticated ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location },
            }}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};

//CheckoutRoute.jsx
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import useCart from "../../hooks/useCart";

const CheckoutRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  const { isCartEmpty } = useCart();
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) => {
        return !isCartEmpty ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/cart",
              state: { from: location },
            }}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

This works but any route after I add after that, does not work

```
//App.jsx
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        {/* Nesting routes  */}
        <NewAuthenticatedRoute>
          <CheckoutRoute exact path="/checkout">
            <Checkout></Checkout>
          </CheckoutRoute>
          <CheckoutRoute exact path="/payment">
            <StripePayment></StripePayment>
          </CheckoutRoute>
        </NewAuthenticatedRoute> //THESE ROUTES ARE WORKING PERFECTLY
        <Route path="*">
          <NotFound></NotFound>
        </Route> // THIS ROUTE IS NOT WORKING AND DOES NOT CATCH 404
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

I am using React Router DOM v5.

Please help

thank you